# Can we compute the surface area and volume of Penrose Triangle?

Tags: area, volume

Can we compute the surface area and the volume of the [Penrose triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle) as an impossible object, not as a visual illusion?

[image]

I'm interested in this question because I'm trying to find a proof that mathematics cannot distinguish between possible and impossible objects. That is, an object does not necessarily exist because we can compute its mathematical properties.

Thanks.

Comment: Before trying to compute anything, I think you should first provide a mathematical definition of the Penrose triangle...

Comment: Penrose triangle is not impossible. It just cannot be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Bob Ok, do we know if there is mathematical definition of Penrose Triangle?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I don't understand. If it cannot be embedded in three dimensional space, doesn't this mean that it is an impossible object in three dimensional space?

Comment: Yes, but this means you need to correct the sentence "I'm trying to find a proof that mathematics cannot distinguish between *possible and impossible* objects." to something weaker, e.g. "I'm trying to find a proof that mathematics cannot distinguish between objects *embeddable in 3D space and those that are not*." To that the answer is "using areas/volumes is not the way to do it", i.e. you need a different (but still a mathematical) proof that it cannot be embedded.

Comment: As for a suitable mathematical structure that represents Penrose triangle... I don't know a reference, but... make an infinite line linking points $(n,n,n),(n,n,n+1),(n,n+1,n+1),(n+1,n+1,n+1)$ in $\mathbb R^3$, "thicken" it to appear like an infinite "rod", and then with a suitable equivalence we can make a [quotient metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Quotient_metric_spaces) of $\mathbb R^3$ (I guess this will do: $(x,y,z)\sim(x',y',z')\iff (\exists n\in\mathbb Z)(x-x'=y-y'=z-z'=n)$) in which the "rod" will produce Penrose triangle.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The sides in the picture look to be five blocks long, but if you post your last comment using $n + 5$ (or $n + \ell$ for some real $\ell$), thicken each lattice point into a cube of side $1$ (or each path segment into a rectangular solid), and give the area and volume in terms of $5$ (or $\ell$), I'd upvote.

Comment: Thinking as a layman, it is not possible to define this shape in 3D in simple terms the way, for instance, a triangle is defined. Is this correct?

Comment: @zeynel As I said, Penrose triangle does not exist in $\mathbb R^3$ but it can be defined alright as a metric space. See the Wikipedia link in my previous comment. There is a lot more to math that most people ever have a chance to see.

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr: There are at least two questions here: One concerning "impossible objects" and what it means for some mathematical object to "exist," the other about geometry.

1. The terms *exist* and *impossible object* are too coarse to resolve the motivating question

> I'm interested in this question because I'm trying to find a proof that mathematics cannot distinguish between possible and impossible objects. That is, an object does not necessarily exist because we can compute its mathematical properties.

2. The Penrose triangle does not isometrically embed in Euclidean three-space, but it *is* a well-defined object that can be embedded in the product of a Euclidean plane and a circle. Assuming the square cross section has unit area and each "side" has length $\ell$ (the case $\ell = 4$ is shown in the diagram below, but general can be any real number greater than $1$), the volume is $3\ell$ (cubic units) and the surface area is $12\ell$ (square units).

[image: The Penrose triangle unwrapped in Euclidean three-space]

### Existence and Impossibility

Consider the questions

- Does there exist a triangle with four sides?
- Does there exist a triangle with three interior right angles?
- Do triangles exist?

To answer any of these, we need a definition of *triangle*, but we also need to agree what is meant by *exist*. For the second we need in addition a definition of *right angle*.

#### Euclidean Geometry

Suppose we define a *triangle* to be a Euclidean plane figure comprising three line segments (the *sides*) such that each pair of sides meet at precisely one common endpoint (a *vertex* of the triangle), and each side meets the other two sides.

In this setting *there does not exist* a triangle with four sides in the sense that a triangle with four sides is *logically self-contradictory*. The same argument can be used in any setting where a *triangle* is a figure with three sides.

In the same setting *there does not exist* a triangle with three interior right angles: In Euclidean geometry, we can prove the sum of the interior angles of a triangle is a straight angle, i.e., two right angles.

Finally, we might agree that *triangles exist* because there are constructs within Euclidean geometry satisfying the definition.

Alternatively, we might agree that *triangles do not exist* because triangles, and Euclidean geometry itself, and arguably all of mathematics, are mere idealizations of the physical world around us.

These considerations illustrate why we need to exercise care to speak of *impossibility*.

#### Spherical Geometry

Let's revisit the second question. Suppose we define a *triangle* to be a spherical figure comprising three arcs of great circles (the *sides*) such that each pair of sides meet at precisely one common endpoint (a *vertex* of the triangle), and each side meets the other two sides.

In this setting, *there exists a triangle having three interior right angles*. For example, take two longitudes meeting perpendicularly and extending from one pole to the equator, and close the figure with the quarter-equator joining the "free" endpoints.

If the sphere is assumed to have Euclidean radius $R$ (or spherical diameter $\pi R$ if we want to refer only to intrinsic geometry), a "triple-right" triangle has perimeter $\frac{3}{2}\pi R$ and area $\frac{1}{2}\pi R^{2}$.

To a Euclidean plane mathematician, such a figure is *impossible* in the sense of *logically incompatible with theorems of Euclidean plane geometry*. To a spherical mathematician, a triple-right triangle is one-eighth of a globe.

### The Penrose Triangle

Logically, the considerations about Euclidean versus spherical triangles parallel the question about the Penrose triangle. The Penrose triangle is not logically self-contradictory. Nonetheless, with a suitable definition involving three equal-length sides of square cross section meeting perpendicularly, a Penrose triangle is [*incompatible with three-dimensional Euclidean geometry*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635774/how-can-i-understand-is-the-picture-2d-or-3d).

On the other hand, as noted by Stinking Bishop in the comments, there exists a three-dimensional universe with locally-Euclidean geometry, topologically the product of the Euclidean plane and a circle, in which the Penrose triangle does exist as a mathematical object, analogously to a triple-right triangle on a sphere.

---

[image: The Penrose triangle unwrapped in Euclidean three-space]

In Euclidean three-space, consider the infinite object made by concatenating successive $1 \times 1 \times \ell$ blocks parallel to the Cartesian coordinate axes in cyclic succession. More precisely, place a copy with opposite corners at $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(\ell, 1, 1)$; place a second copy with corners at $(\ell+1, 0, 0)$ and $(\ell, \ell, 1)$; place a third copy with corners at $(\ell + 1, \ell + 1, 0)$ and $(\ell, \ell, \ell)$. Call the union of these three pieces a *fundamental unit*.

The chain is now extended by translating the fundamental unit by integer multiples of $(\ell, \ell, \ell)$. With $\ell = 4$ as in the diagram, the union is a doubly-infinite ordered list of unit cubes, each with two attached faces and four unattached faces. Whether or not $\ell$ is an integer, the fundamental unit has volume $3\ell$ and exposed surface area $12\ell$ *in the infinite chain*.

Introduce a Cartesian coordinate system $(x, y, z)$ whose first two axes are perpendicular to $(1, 1, 1)$ and whose third axis is parallel to $(1, 1, 1)$. Let the additive group $(\mathbf{Z}, +)$ act as translation by multiples of $(\ell, \ell, \ell)$, i.e.,
$$
n \cdot (x, y, z) = (x, y, z) + n\ell(1, 1, 1).
$$
The "slab" $D = \{(x, y, z) : 0 \leq z \leq \ell\sqrt{3}\}$ is a fundamental domain for the group action, and the infinite chain of fundamental units is invariant under the group action. Since translations are isometries, all the geometry descends to the quotient. The ambient space is the product of a Euclidean plane and an orthogonal circle of circumference $\ell\sqrt{3}$. The image of the fundamental unit is a topological loop with its "initial" cube abutting the "final" cube, i.e., a Penrose triangle.

While a Penrose does *exist* in this locally-Euclidean quotient space, it does not exist (embed isometrically as a subset) in Euclidean three-space: If we start at the corner $(0, 0, 0)$ of the fundamental unit and travel successively to $(\ell, 0, 0)$, $(\ell, \ell, 0)$, and $(\ell, \ell, \ell)$, we return to our initial location in the Penrose triangle (as indicated by any of the blue arrows), but we do not return to our initial location in Euclidean space.